# How to convert InputStream to a PDF in Java, without damaging the file?

Tags: java, pdf

I have an InputStream which I would like to convert to a PDF, and save that PDF in a directory. Currently, my code is able to convert the InputStream to a PDF and the PDF does show up in the correct directory. However, when I try to open it, the file is damaged.

Here is the current code:

```
 InputStream pAdESStream = signingServiceConnector.getDirectClient().getPAdES(this.statusReader.getStatusResponse().getpAdESUrl()); 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[pAdESStream.available()];
            pAdESStream.read(buffer);

            File targetFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "targetFile2.pdf");
            OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
            outStream.write(buffer);
```

Originally, the InputStream was a pAdES-file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAdES). However, it should be able to be read as just a regular PDF.

Does anyone know how to convert the InputStream to a PDF, without getting a damaged PDF as a result?

Comment: First thing to do is stop using `available()`. To read a stream completely, you should generally loop until `read()` returns -1. There are various third party libraries to simplify this, but fundamentally it's not terribly hard... typically you read into a buffer, copying into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Alternatively, if you're *just* copying the stream to a file, just loop reading from your input stream and writing to the file.

Comment: Just to stress @Jon's point: there are only very few `InputStream` implementations which return the full file size by `available`, in particular the `FileInputStream`. Most others merely return the bytes already fetched and residing e.g. in some buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello it might be a bit late but you can use PDFBOX api (or itextpdf) 
https://www.tutorialkart.com/pdfbox/create-write-text-pdf-file-using-pdfbox/
here is a tuto of the process gl